# Add item to top of list and scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel this should be simple, but I can't get my head round how to do it.

I want to add new items to the top of a list, and have the list scroll down to reveal the new item.

The closest I've got so far is here: http://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/cmsh0zoz/4/ This creates and adds a new list item by doing:

```
var content = 'Hello';
if (Math.random() < 0.3) {
    content += '<br/>Another line';
};

$('<li>').html(content)
            .hide()
            .prependTo( $('ul') )
            .slideDown('slow', function() {
                // Remove final element:
                $('ul').find('li:gt(9)').remove();
            });
```

That reveals the new item by having it `slideDown`, which isn't quite what I want - I want it to be as if the new item has appeared behind the "Test list" heading, and then the whole list slides down to reveal it.

Note that list items have varying heights, which complicates things slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `slideDown`, considering animating the `ul`'s top margin, starting with the negative height of the newly-added element (including padding).

First, add this to your `h1` style:

```
position: relative;
```

That effectively puts the `h1`' on top of the `ul`.  (See [css positioning z-index negative margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157005/css-positioning-z-index-negative-margins) for why we can't use z-index for this.)

You can then animate the `ul` like this:

```
function scroll() {
  var content = 'Hello';
  if (Math.random() < 0.3) {
    content += '<br/>Another line';
  };
  $('ul').prepend('<li>'+content)
         .css('margin-top',-$('li').first().outerHeight(true))
         .delay(1000)
         .animate({'margin-top':0},
                  function() {
                    $(this).find('li:gt(9)').remove();
                    scroll();
                  }
                 );
};
```

Calling the `scroll` function after the animation is finished may be better than using `setInterval`, because it guarantees that scrolling won't occur until after the previous scroll.  The `delay` keeps it from running continuously.

Fiddle at:  **http://jsfiddle.net/w0gnzqx6/8/**

Comment: Oh, that's good, thanks Rick! There's a bit of a jerk though, when the element is prepended and the negative margin is set. I guess a slight mismatch in timing between the two things happening? Any thoughts on how to make it smoother?

Comment: You're right, I wasn't accounting for the `li` padding.  I've updated my answer.  I also eliminated `setInterval` in my new response.

Comment: That's lovely Rick! I made a tweak to take account of the `li`s' bottom margin, which takes out the final bit of jerkiness: http://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/w0gnzqx6/7/ My real-world example needs a bit of work as it's coping with a live feed of data - I need to stop it updating too quickly. But that's a different problem :)

Comment: Ha, I somehow missed the bottom `margin`, so I'm glad you caught that and changed to 15.  Glad it works.

Comment: Actually, instead of `$('li').first().css('height'))-15` we can do `$('li').first().outerHeight(true)`, which is a bit more future-proof.